# Is there any way to get a snow biome without generating a new map?

Tags: terraria

Just as the title says, is there any way that I can get a snow biome without generating a fresh map in Terraria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need an area with a large number of [snow blocks](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Snow_Block), around 500 will get you the most snow, any more should be unnecessary.

You can use programs like [TEdit](http://terrariatips.com/2011/05/terraria-map-editor-tedit/) to edit your map to have enough blocks. Or you can put them in your inventory using [TerrariViewer](http://terrariviewer.codeplex.com/) and place them manually.

Comment: If you can place them in your inventory, couldn't you just mine them on a new map and place them in your pre-1.1 map, as opposed to resorting to using external programs?

Comment: @oKtosiTe Yes, but he said without rendering a new map.

Comment: Well when I said without creating a new map, I just meant being forced to start over.

Comment: @ryansworld10: I assumed that was what you meant. :-)